# Execute select statement IF table exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, psql, postgresql-9.6

FINAL PURPOSE: **Generate a query that, if a table exists, execute a statement for that table**

I'm trying to execute a PSQL (9.6) statement only if a certain table exists in the schema, but it always responds with a syntax error each time I try to use conditional `IF`.

My query is something like...

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'users') THEN
  SELECT * FROM users;
END IF;
```

And the output is...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE tabl...
        ^
```

*There is no more code than this*. All alternatives that I tried failed.

Comment: Try `SELECT IF EXISTS`

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.  Parsing the `SELECT` will fail if the table doesn't exist.

Comment: That statement has to be in a PL/pgSQL block. Either you don't have it in such a block or you have an error already before the `IF`. If you got it in a block, please show the whole block.

Comment: @stickybit there is no other block involved. How it would be written with a PL/pgSQL block?

Answer (score 11):

You could (and likely have to) wrap that in a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION select_if_exists
                ()
RETURNS TABLE (id integer,
               foo text)
AS
$$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                   FROM information_schema.tables
                   WHERE table_schema = current_schema()
                         AND table_name = 'elbat') THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT elbat.id,
                        elbat.foo
                        FROM elbat;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you call

```
SELECT *
       FROM select_if_exists();
```

when the table does not exist you get the empty set.

Create the table, call it again and you'll get the contents of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             AS SELECT 1::integer id,
                       'Hello World!'::text foo;

SELECT *
       FROM select_if_exists();
```

But you cannot distinguish from outside, just by calling the function, if you got an empty set because the table doesn't exist or because it is empty. You'd have to `RAISE` an error then (But if you want that you could have just used a normal `SELECT` that croaks anyway, if the target table doesn't exist.)

And the table has to have the expected columns. Otherwise the `SELECT` in the function fails.

Notice: If you actually don't want to return a query result but execute a DML (or a DDL should work too) you could also put it in an anonymous block without defining a function. Example:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT *
                   FROM information_schema.tables
                   WHERE table_schema = current_schema()
                         AND table_name = 'elbat') THEN
    DELETE FROM elbat;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Good approach! My idea is to use it to create some SQL Views, so its quite difficult to use this but, by now, is the only solution that seems to work

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name
 WHERE EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
        AND table_name = 'table_name'
    );
```

Comment: I downvote you because you miss the other half of the question

Comment: There is no error, but you only are checking if a table exists. My problem is that I cannot find a solution to execute a query if this is true.

Comment: have you try to run this solution

Comment: Yes, and it say that exists. Only this.

Comment: you have to just modify a query. I will do that for you.please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172416/discussion-between-kaval-patel-and-marc-rs).

Comment: This does not work because the query parser will reject `FROM table_name` if it does not exist, even before starting execution of the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the below code:

```
select * from users
where exists (select table_name 
from information_schema.tables
where table_name = 'users');
```

However if you provide your complete block/purpose it would help in giving you a better result.

Updated Query:

```
if (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_name = 
'order') = 1 
SELECT * FROM "order" ;
else print N'No Table';
```

Results when run without a table and with a valid table:

----No Table

----(830 row(s) affected)

Comment: Nope, another fail
`ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist`

Comment: With the updated query it fails to, with
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"`
`LINE 1: if (select count(*) from information_schema.tables where tab...`
`       ^`

Answer (score -1):

To do it with query instead of function, here is the sql code:

```
select 'users_EXISTS', table_name,
   case
       when table_name = null then 0
       else 1
   end
    as table_exists 
from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'users';
```

In else instead of 1, you can put your statement for "**execute a statement**"